# AWS elastic beanstalk configure multiple services with custom subdomains with SSL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have big problem with AWS. I want to use Elastic Beanstalk to run my three services by multi-docker.
I prepared the Dockerrun.aws.json with multiple containers. It starts successfull -- I saw it in logs.

Now I have problem with access configuration. I want to use subdomains to connect each my service, I want also add the ssl and https redirect.

I know that I need to use loadbalancer in EB -- I have tried with Application and Classic loadbalancer (but maybe I don't know how to configure it).

Client have cloudeflare and I can't set custom AWS dns in Route53.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add two layers of load balancers. The first one will be an **Application Load Balancer (ALB)** and the second will be **Nginx**.

## First Layer of Load Balancer

The **ALB** will sit on top of your Beanstalk instance. It is the link between Cloudflare (or whatever DNS provider you are using) and your servers running on Elastic Beanstalk. The general steps are as follows;

1. User request goes to Cloudflare
2. Route53 directs the request to Application Load Balancer (ALB)
3. ALB handles HTTP to HTTPS redirects and routes the request to Elastic Beanstalk.

### Supporting multiple subdomains

1. Create a sub-domain on Cloudflare and point it to your Load Balancers public IP address. It should not changes unless you rebuild your Elastic Beanstalk instance.
2. Go to the EC2 Console **>** **Load Balancers** (Side Menu) **>** **Targets** Tab.
3. You should see a Target already defined for your Load Balancer which will include the Elastic Beanstalk instance. If not, you need to "Register" your instance for your Load Balancer's target.
4. Then open the **Load Balancers** Tab **>** Select your Load Balancer **>** Open the **Listeners** tab at the bottom.
5. Here you'll see a table with two records for listeners **PORT 80 (HTTP)** and **PORT 443 (HTTPS)**.
6. In the **Rules** column press **View/edit rules**
7. Here you can define how your load balancer will behave on different URLs, routes, or query params.
8. Click on the **+ (plus)** symbol to add new rules. The rule you want to set is;

**For PORT 443**

```
IF **HOST HEADER** > **SUB DOMAIN**
THEN **Forward To** > **Select Target Group**
```

**For PORT 80 (Redirects)**

```
IF **HOST HEADER** > **SUB DOMAIN** (with http)
THEN **Redirect To** > **Enter Port 433 and leave everything else the same**
```

> NOTE: you may also need to create and attach a certificate from ACM. This step can also be done from Beanstalk Console.

## Second Layer of Load Balancer

After that the second layer **Nginx** comes into play. As soon as the request hits port 80 on the instance **Nginx** will catch it. You will need to edit the default config file for Nginx to so redirect requests on certain URLs to your specified services. The general steps are;

1. Create a config file in the `.ebextensions` folder with the updated config file.
2. This file should replace the default config Nginx file on the instance.

> Refer to the AWS Docs to configure a reverse proxy [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-se-nginx.html).

---

After that, the Application Load Balancer should redirect traffic on multiple sub-domains to your beanstalk instance and Nginx should redirect traffic to different services based on which URL they come from.

Comment: I have no target, how to configure it?

Comment: You write that Route53 directs the request to ALB – is ti correct? I think I'am not using Route53, I'm using the record A in cloudflare, it it good understanding?

Comment: I have clear AWS, should I create elasticIP for loadbalancer?

Comment: And I can't use ALB because I need to redirect other connections than HTTP/HTTPS

Comment: I'm going to answer your question in the order you asked them.

1) You can google [how to add target to load balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/create-target-group.html)

2) Yes that should be fine.

3) I don't think you need an Elastic IP. Just use the public IP provided by AWS for the load balancer.

4) ALB does provide HTTPS redirect, as already instructed in the answer, you can also explore **Network Load Balancer** and see if it fits your use case.